# Доработка сайта на битрикс

Tags: битрикс, битрикс24

Нужно создать еще одну страницу на сайте, который сделан на битриксе. Через админку в оглавление я ее добавил, шаблон, по всей видимости, созданный кем-то до меня, применил, проблема заключается в том, что не могу разобраться как наполнить сайт информацией, различными элементами и т.п. Нужно скачать все файлы и редактировать их через редактор кода или делать это в конструкторе? Ранее занимался фронтендом и это для меня не представляло сложности, но битрикс... меня пугает, все разбито по папкам, куча php файлов, непонятно что с ними делать. Хотелось бы объяснения для начала работы или ссылки на видео или статьи, в которых это показывается, может быть я сам не то искал, но все видео и статьи скорее из разряда 2 + 2 = 4

Comment: Вообще у Битрикса на сайте есть очень неплохие курсы: https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/learning/index.php#tab-online-link

Answer (score 0):

Если я правильно понял проблему, то страницу Вы создали, она физически имеется на сайте, на неё можно зайти, но Вы не знаете как её редактировать. Это можно сделать двумя способами - из публичной части и из админки.

**Публичная часть**

1. Заходите на свою страницу и включаете в правом верхнем углу режим правки:
   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
2. Наводите курсор на область контента Вашей страницы (в моём примере это фраза "Тестовая страница", у Вам может не быть никакого контента, но редактируемая область всё равно обозначится при наведении):
   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
3. Открываете страницу в редакторе - здесь можно писать свою разметку:
   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Админка**

1. Заходите во вкладку "Администрирование" (сверху), там в боковом меню выбираете "Файлы и папки" и открываете раздел (не просто разворачиваете, а именно открываете, чтобы содержимое появилось в рабочей области):
   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
2. Там находите php-файл своей страницы (если Вы создали раздел, а не страницу, то это будет папка, в которую надо зайти и в ней редактировать index.php):
   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Стили и в первом, и во втором случае следует писать в "стили сайта" (впрочем, можно и в стили шаблона - на результате это не скажется):
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Важно:** Помните, что Битрикс очень любит всё кешировать, и внесённые изменения в стилевые файлы могут не подхватиться - для этого надо зайти в админку, выбрать в левом боковом меню "Настройки", там "Автокеширование" и почтить кеш (или отключить его на время отладки, чтобы сразу видеть вносимые изменения на сайт).